# ETW Tracing Microsoft-Windows-Win32k SendMessage parameters

Tags: windows

I want to trace the parameters to Send/PostMessage with the Win32K ETW Provider. It has corresponding events but the parameters

- message
- WParam
- LParam

are always empty. Am I missing a switch here or are these values despite beeing present in the ETW data never logged?

[image]

The provider has a bunch of keywords but even using 0xfff.. does not change the situation.

```
            Value               Keyword              Description
            0x0000000000000400  AuditApiCalls
            0x0000000000000800  CompatImpact
            0x0000000000001000  Updates
            0x0000000000002000  Focus
            0x0000000000004000  UIPI
            0x0000000000008000  win32Power
            0x0000000000010000  Concurrency
            0x0000000000020000  UserActivity
            0x0000000000040000  UIUnresponsiveness
            0x0000000000080000  ThreadRundown
            0x0000000000100000  Rendering
            0x0000000000200000  ThreadInfo
            0x0000000000400000  MessagePump
            0x0000000000800000  MessagePumpInternalAndInput
            0x0000000001000000  TouchInput
            0x0000000002000000  TimerSurvey
            0x0000000004000000  PointerInput
            0x0000000008000000  AutoRotation
            0x0000000010000000  Contention
            0x0000000020000000  TimerInfo
            0x0000000040000000  ComponentHosting
            0x0000000080000000  TrappedACRendering
            0x0000000100000000  Fonts
            0x0000000200000000  NullMessages
            0x0000000400000000  Visualization
            0x0000000800000000  DCompDetails
            0x0000001000000000  PrecisionTouchpad
            0x0000002000000000  ContentionTelemetry
            0x0000004000000000  ProcessInfo
            0x0000008000000000  DCompInput
            0x0000010000000000  GdiHandleOperation
            0x0000020000000000  UserHandleOperation
            0x0000040000000000  WriteClipboard
            0x0001000000000000  win:ResponseTime     Response Time
            0x8000000000000000  Microsoft-Windows-Win32k/Tracing
            0x4000000000000000  Microsoft-Windows-Win32k/UIPI
            0x2000000000000000  Microsoft-Windows-Win32k/Power
            0x1000000000000000  Microsoft-Windows-Win32k/Concurrency
            0x0800000000000000  Microsoft-Windows-Win32k/Render
            0x0400000000000000  Microsoft-Windows-Win32k/Messages
            0x0200000000000000  Microsoft-Windows-Win32k/Contention
            0x0100000000000000  Microsoft-Windows-Win32k/Operational
```

To test it you need to install the Windows Performance Toolkit which brings xperf

```
xperf -on proc_thread -start uisession -on Microsoft-Windows-Win32k:0x8400030000240000
xperf -stop -stop uisession && xperf -merge c:\kernel.etl c:\user.etl c:\temp\win32ktrace.etl
```

Then you can load the resulting ETL file into WPA

Comment: Run it elevated if you want it to work with elevated apps.

Comment: @Mark: Kernel Tracing will always need Admin rights. There is very little you can profile at user level.

Comment: You aren't kernel tracing but sendmessage. Normally you use Spy++ for that.

Comment: @Mark: C>xperf -start uisession -on Microsoft-Windows-Win32k:0x8400030000240000
xperf: error: uisession: Access is denied. (0x5). Is a clear sign of needed admin rights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging further it looks like

- Message
- wParam
- lParam

are all set to 0 if the message is not a mouse button Up/Down message. In effect Win32K provider is largely useless with regards to the messages sent to Windows.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).